# proof of function of set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let f be a function from the set A to the set B. Let S and T be subsets of A.

Show that $ f (S ∩ T) ⊆ f (S) ∩ f (T).$

My attemption:

For every y:

y ∈ f (S ∩ T)

=∃x( f (x)=y ∧ (x∈S∩T) )

=∃x( f (x)=y ∧ (x∈S ∧ x∈T))   /defintion of intersection

=∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈S) ∧ ∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈T) /disturbtion of p and(q and r)=(p and q) and (p and r)

=f(S)∩f(T)

ref to:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/591416

Does above prove that  f (S ∩ T)=f(S)∩f(T)?

But we know that f(S)∩f(T) cannot impile f (S ∩ T), which step is wrong in my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

''∃x( f (x)=y ∧ (x∈S ∧ x∈T)) /defintion of intersection

=∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈S) ∧ ∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈T) /disturbtion of p and(q and r)=(p and q) and (p and r)''

This is seen as an equivalence, but its only an implication $\Rightarrow$ because of the quantor.

Comment: but why ∃x( f (x)=y ∧ (x∈S ∨ x∈T)) 

=∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈S) ∨ ∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈T) ?Should i crame for it?

Comment: Its clear that $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: thanks,i knew how to prove A∩B⊆A∪B,but how it related to the logical statement?
∃x( f (x)=y ∧ (x∈S ∨ x∈T)) =∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈S) ∨ ∃x( f (x)=y ∧ x∈T)